# Find matching pairs or chains of persons in dataframe, based on equality of conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I am a beginner in Python - first I want to apologize for my rather long question and the probably very ugly program I wrote to solve my "problem".

The problem is the following: Imagine an exchange of houses for vacation. People can exchange their houses for a vacation among each other. Person 1 from "A" wants to go to "B", person 2 from "B" wants to go to "A". Then a match or barter is achieved and both are no longer available for further matches. In addition, the case should be covered, that person 1 wants to go from "A" to "B", person 2 from "B" to "C" and thus no direct matching would be possible. However, person 3 who wants to go from "C" to "A". Then a trade in this chain of 3 would be possible. People can also chose to specify no specific destination and could therefore go to any place if someone wants to go to their place instead.

All cities are stored in dictionaries, which contain all places within a defined radius of the respective city, so that it is also possible to find a suitable accommodation in a wider area and not only a specific city for example.

The dataset looks like this:

```
name, from, to, matching partner

person1, a, b,
person2, b, a,
person3, a, b,
person4, b, c,
person5, c, a,
```

After my algorithm:

```
name, from, to, matching partner

person1, a, b,person2
person2, b, a,person1
person3, a, b,person4person5
person4, b, c,person5person3
person5, c, a,person3person4
```

This is how I implemented it with my Python program:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

data = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", delimiter=";")

#Fill Missing Data in column "matchingpartner"
data.loc[:,"matchingpartner"] = data.loc[:,"matchingpartner"].fillna("no partner yet")

#Decide which Search Distance should be used (dict_5 for 5miles, dict_10 for 10miles, dict_9000 for 9000miles)
dict_postcode = dict_10

#Matching: Direkt 1:1 or Chain with 3 Persons
for x in range(0,data.shape[0]):
    for y in range(1,data.shape[0]): 
        for z in range(2,data.shape[0]): 
            if (x==y) | (x==z) | (y==z):
                continue
             #1 search for direct matching partners:
            if (    ((str(data.loc[x,"to"]) in dict_postcode[str(data.loc[y,"from"])]) or data.loc[x,"to"] =="dontcare") 
                and ((str(data.loc[y,"to"]) in dict_postcode[str(data.loc[x,"from"])]) or data.loc[y,"to"] =="dontcare")
                #only for persons without existing matching partner
                and (data.loc[x,"matchingpartner"] == "no partner yet") 
                and (data.loc[y,"matchingpartner"] == "no partner yet")):
                    data.loc[x,"matchingpartner"] = data.loc[y,"name"]
                    data.loc[y,"matchingpartner"] = data.loc[x,"name"]

            #2 If pairwise matching from #1 did not work, try to build matching chains of 3 or more
            elif (   str(data.loc[x,"to"]) in dict_postcode[str(data.loc[y,"from"])]  or data.loc[x,"to"] =="dontcare")     
                and (str(data.loc[y,"to"]) in dict_postcode[str(data.loc[z,"from"])]  or data.loc[y,"to"] =="dontcare")    
                and (str(data.loc[z,"to"]) in dict_postcode[str(data.loc[x,"from"])]  or data.loc[z,"to"] =="dontcare")   
                #only for persons without existing matching partner
                and (data.loc[x,"matchingpartner"] == "no partner yet")
                and (data.loc[y,"matchingpartner"] == "no partner yet")
                and (data.loc[z,"matchingpartner"] == "no partner yet")):
                    data.loc[x,"matchingpartner"] = data.loc[y,"name"] + data.loc[z,"name"]
                    data.loc[y,"matchingpartner"] = data.loc[z,"name"] + data.loc[x,"name"] 
                    data.loc[z,"matchingpartner"] = data.loc[x,"name"] +data.loc[y,"name"]
```

It works and delivers my desired output BUT it is super-slow.
Question 1: Do you know a more elegant and efficient way to solve this? The runtime is very long right now. My dataset has around 400.000 observations.

Question 2: Right now, due to the slow speed of the algorithm, I only allow chains of 3 persons. Do you know how I could generalize this procedure without for loops maybe, so I could define a certain maximum chain size (e.g. 5 Persons, 1 wants from a to b, 2 from b to c, 3 from c to d, 4 from d to e and 5 from e to a)?

Answer (score 0):

This can be represented as a [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) where the nodes represent the persons and edges indicate whether a person could move to another person's home. In general you can use [`np.equal.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) for computing the host candidates and then use [`networkx`](https://pypi.org/project/networkx/) to create the corresponding graph. For example:

```
           home destination
Carole        A           C
Irvin         A           D
Kelvin        C           A
Stanley       A           D
Lazaro        E           C
Yong          C           A
Florentino    B           E
Jose          C           E
Bettye        B           E
Clinton       A           D
Georgia       A           D
Lon           A           E
Ezra          C           D
Tim           A           E
Mae           A           B

# Create the graph by feeding the edges.
graph = nx.DiGraph()
graph.add_edges_from(np.argwhere(np.equal.outer(df['destination'], df['home'])))
```

Some attributes of the resulting graph:

```
graph.number_of_nodes()  # 15
graph.number_of_edges()  # 31
list(graph.edges())  # [(0, 2), (0, 5), (0, 7), (0, 12), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 9), (2, 10), (2, 11), (2, 13), (2, 14), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 9), (5, 10), (5, 11), (5, 13), (5, 14), (7, 4), (11, 4), (13, 4), (14, 6), (14, 8), (4, 2), (4, 5), (4, 7), (4, 12), (6, 4), (8, 4)]
```

### Finding possible candidates

Now we can obtain sets of possible candidates by searching for cycles in that graph (a cycle means that everyone moving to another home will also rent out theirs); we can use `nx.simple_cycles`:

> Find simple cycles (elementary circuits) of a directed graph.
>
> A `simple cycle`, or `elementary circuit`, is a closed path where
>   no node appears twice. Two elementary circuits are distinct if they
>   are not cyclic permutations of each other.

```
list(nx.simple_cycles(graph))  # [[0, 7, 4, 5], [0, 7, 4, 2], [0, 5, 14, 8, 4, 2], [0, 5, 14, 6, 4, 2], [0, 5, 13, 4, 2], [0, 5, 11, 4, 2], [0, 5], [0, 2, 14, 8, 4, 5], [0, 2, 14, 6, 4, 5], [0, 2, 13, 4, 5], [0, 2, 11, 4, 5], [0, 2], [2, 14, 8, 4], [2, 14, 6, 4], [2, 13, 4], [2, 11, 4], [4, 7], [4, 5, 14, 8], [4, 5, 14, 6], [4, 5, 13], [4, 5, 11]]
```

### Finding the best mapping

#### Greedy approach

In order to find an optimal solution we can treat each cycle as a set of nodes and we would need to find the combination of disjoint sets that has the largest magnitude. This is a computationally demanding problem and hence a greedy solution might be preferable (i.e. just adding cycles one after another and discarding those that are not disjoint with the accumulated set). For example:

```
# Greedy approach.
cycles = []
nodes = set()
for cycle in nx.simple_cycles(graph):
    if nodes.isdisjoint(cycle):
        cycles.append(cycle)
        nodes.update(cycle)
```

This gives `cycles == [[0, 7, 4, 5]]` which however is not the optimal solution.

#### Optimal solution

If computationally feasible it can be found brute-force by using another graph representing the compatible (i.e. disjoint) sets; we add the empty set so we can use the magnitude of other sets (the length of the corresponding cycles) as edge weights:

```
import itertools as it

all_cycles = list(nx.simple_cycles(graph))
disjoint = np.zeros((len(all_cycles),)*2 , dtype=bool)
disjoint[np.triu_indices(disjoint.shape[0], k=1)] = list(map(
    lambda x: set.isdisjoint(*x),
    it.combinations(map(set, all_cycles), 2)
))

# Add the empty set as a starting point, so we can use cycle length as edge weight.
disjoint = np.concatenate([np.ones((1, disjoint.shape[1]), dtype=bool), disjoint], axis=0)
disjoint = np.concatenate([np.zeros((disjoint.shape[0], 1), dtype=bool), disjoint], axis=1)
lengths = np.fromiter(map(len, [[]] + all_cycles), dtype=int)
indices = np.argwhere(disjoint)

c_graph = nx.DiGraph()
c_graph.add_edges_from(zip(indices[:, 0], indices[:, 1], ({'weight': l} for l in lengths)))
best_combination = nx.dag_longest_path(c_graph, 'weight')
```

The result is `[0, 7, 13]`. Note that this includes the empty set as 0-th index so we need to offset each index by `-1`. Hence the final solution is compound of the cycles `[[0, 5], [2, 14, 8, 4]]` which have total length of 6. Effectively this means that

- `Carole` should switch with `Yong`,
- and `Kelvin -> Mae -> Bettye -> Lazaro -> Kelvin`.

### Scalability

Now all this is computationally not easy and for your example of 400,000 samples it won't be possible. Already the `np.equal.outer` has O(N^2) memory consumption and hence ends up with ~ 20 GiB. Here you can build the graph also incrementally by iterating through the data frame row by row. Nevertheless the resulting graph may be so complex that it is still unfeasible to compute all cycles for example.

Another option for scaling this to larger data sets is to give up on guaranteed optimality by randomly splitting the data set into subsets each of which is small enough for the algorithm to work. Then results are obtained for each subset and merged to a global result. By performing multiple such random splits and comparing the individual results one can yet improve on the solution.

Instead of splitting the data set one can also sample subsets, solve for the subset and then put back to the pool those persons that have not been matched. Similarly in the splitting approach you can pool together all unmatched persons after one round of splitting and then continue iteratively.

Comment: thank you very much! This is definitely so much more elegant than my nested loops! Another question is, how can I use this to build cycles or matching pairs, if more than one condition has to be equal. For example all people have to be available at the same period of time? Is it possible to implement something like this?

Comment: @luxeluxe Sure, the edges in the graph describe whether two people match together or not, no matter on how many conditions this is based. I.e. you would add an edge only if all the conditions for a match are satisfied.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not quite sure, how to alter your code to also make sure that the other conditions have to hold in order to generate matches. I wrote another "Answer" because the comment section is to short for this. Sorry for the many questions

Answer (score 0):

```
| NAME       | home | destination | From       | Until      | howlong | HAS    | WANTS  |
|------------|------|-------------|------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|
| Carole     | A    | B           | 01.01.2020 | 01.02.2020 | 5days   | 2rooms | 3rooms |
| Irvin      | B    | A           | 01.01.2020 | 01.02.2020 | 5days   | 3rooms | 2rooms |
| Kelvin     | A    | B           | 02.06.2021 | 05.08.2021 | 9days   | 1room  | 2rooms |
| Stanley    | B    | C           | 02.05.2021 | 05.08.2021 | 9days   | 2rooms | 3rooms |
| Lazaro     | C    | A           | 20.05.2021 | 05.08.2021 | 9days   | 3rooms | 1room  |
| Yong       | A    | B           | 01.01.2020 | 03.05.2020 | 20days  | 1room  | 1room  |
| Florentino | B    | A           | 04.05.2020 | 08.08.2020 | 20days  | 1room  | 1room  |
```

I'm not quite sure, how to alter your code to also make sure that the other conditions have to hold in order to generate matches. These should include

1. the columns "From" and "Until" as first condition, have to overlap, the persons can only be part of a match, if there time periods of "From" to "Until" overlap AND additionally the "howlong" column must be equal for the matching partners.
   I implemented this in my code by adding it as another if-statement within the code block in my initial question:

   ```
   #Define function that checks if temporal matching between 2 people is possible     
   #Conditions:         
       # 1 The specified periods derived from start and end date must overlap             
       # ((s1 <= s2 & e2 <= e1) | (s2 <= s1 & e1 <= e2))         
       # 2 Start date of Person2 + desired duration of Person1 must be before the end      date of Person 2         
       # 3 Start date of Person1 + desired duration of Person2 must be before the end    date of Person 1
   def timechecker(start1,end1,duration1,start2,end2,duration2):
   if (((start1<=start2) and (end2<=end1)) or ((start2<=start1) and (end1<=end2)) and (start2+duration1<=end2) and (start1+duration2<=end1)):
   return True
   else:
   return False

   #Time Matching
   if...
   ...
           and ((timechecker(data.loc[x,'From'],data.loc[x,'Until'],data.loc[x,'duration'],data.loc[y,'From'],data.loc[y,'Until'],data.loc[y,'duration'])))
   ```
2. As second condition the "HAS" and "WANTS" columns follow the same logic as the "home" and "destination" columns so I guess the code would look like this:

   ```
   graph.add_edges_from(np.argwhere(np.equal.outer(df['destination'], df['home']) and
     np.equal.outer(df['HAS'], df['WANTS'])))
   ```
3. Is it possible to set a limit to how "big" the cycles can be? Is it feasible to allow only cycles of e.g. 3 or 5 persons?